# My await variables in my async function don't seem to execute line by line

Tags: async-await, jsx

I have two variables that await functions. I am simply trying to console log them after they are done, however I get undefined for both of them as it skips past.

The console log which happens after the await functions occurs first. Then the functions complete a few seconds later.

```
async onSubmit(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   const coverImage = await ipfs.files.add(this.state.buffer, (error, result) =>{
   if(error){
    console.error(error)
    return
   }

  console.log('Here is: ', result[0].hash)
  //Return the hash value
  return result[0].hash
  })

  const contents = await ipfs.files.add(this.state.contentBuffer, (error, result) =>{
  if(error){
    console.error(error)
    return
  }

  console.log('Here is: ', result[0].hash)
  //Return the hash value
  return result[0].hash
  })

  let answer ={thePic: coverImage, theContents: contents}

  console.log(answer)   //This shows as {thePic: undefined, theContents: 
  //undefined}

}
```

I would expect the console log after `coverImage` and `theContents` are finished, but it happens right away.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're actually doing because of formatting (and that's why I didn't "fix" it), and what the functions you're attempting to `await` actually do--because it *looks* like you're passing in callbacks, implying they're not actually async, hence there's nothing to `await`.

Comment: The strange thing is that your code uses both `await` and callback functions. Are you sure `ipfs.files.add` actually returns a Promise? Mind showing us the docs for what `ipfs.files.add` does?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Yes, reading the `ipfs.files.add` documentation made me realize clearer what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/ipfs/interface-ipfs-core/blob/master/SPEC/FILES.md#add

"If no callback is passed, a promise is returned."

`await` only makes sense if you're calling a function that returns a promise.
If you modify your code to continue in the async function after the async call, the returned value should be the result you're looking for, and happen in the order you expect.

```
const imageResult = await ipfs.files.add(this.state.buffer);
const coverImage = imageResult[0].hash;
```

If you want to handle error conditions, wrap the whole set of await'd calls in a try/catch; the error will be that thrown by any of the intermediate promises' error conditions.

Comment: Yes, this was essentially the answer. I just had to reread the IPFS documentation to see what I was doing.